# Как расширить зону редактирования в Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет!

При редактировании не вмещается таблица на всю ширину. Возможно ли как-то расширить область редактирования? Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Красная линия - граница зоны редактирования

Comment: Это тема задаёт ширину, которая будет на сайте. Правильное лечение - настроить тему и/или выбрать подходящий шаблон в теме для этой страницы

Comment: Ширину сайта я настроил, и она 100% от страницы, а этот блок не расширился...

Comment: "Ширина сайта" и ширина страницы -разные вещи.

Comment: Очень интересно. Но по существу ничего не понятно.

Comment: И что не понятно из моего первого коммента?